# time delay in YUI3

Tags: yui, timedelay

I know things like this are probably best suited to the YUI forums, but I need an answer asap and I may be a while waiting for the YUI forums.

The problem is, I want to transition something in about 14 seconds after the page loads, I know how to run code onload and how to transition elements, but I really can't figure out (or seem to find any information) on how or (even if it is possible) to run the function with a time delay.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can't you use `setTimeout` to implement that transition?

Comment: I've seen setTimeout in YUI2 discussions, is it implemented the same in 3 too?

Comment: @Pushpesh should probably make that an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

appart from just using the javascript `setTimeout` and assuming YUI 3.

[yui-lang-later has a `later` method that wraps `setTimeout`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_later)

```
var handle = Y.later( 1000 * 14, window, function(){
    // do something 
}, [], false);


// got bored 
handle.cancel(); // will prevent the function being called.
```